# Void como parámetro de una función

Tags: c++

Me he encontrado con este código. El uso del void, ¿es una cuestión estética para indicar que la función no tiene parámetros o realmente esa función espera algo del tipo void?¿Hay un tipo void(al margen del uso que se le da para declarar una función que no devuelve nada)?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código que has puesto parece más código en C que en C++. No sé si la etiqueta es la adecuada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La palabra `void`, puede aparecer como parámetro de una función, para indicar que no recibe parámetros, como tipo retornado, para indicar que la función no retorna nada, o como tipo de un puntero, como aquí:

```
void *p;
```

Este último caso es interesante. ¿Qué puede significar un puntero a "nada"? En este contexto `void` no se entiende como "nada", sino más bien como "lo que sea". La declaración anterior simplemente declara un puntero, pero "no quiere" entrar en detalles de lo que hay en el lugar apuntado.

Un puntero así podría ser utilizado más tarde para apuntar a un entero, o a un real, o a un carácter, cualquier cosa. Para reservar memoria para él se usaría `malloc()` normalmente, y la cantidad de bytes a reservar depende de cómo pretendamos usarlo luego. Por ejemplo, si quiero guardar un `float` en la dirección apuntada por `p` necesitaré reservar el número de bytes que ocupa un `float`:

```
p = malloc(sizeof(float));
```

Pero para asignarle después un valor será necesario usar un *casting* ya que de lo contrario, si lo usamos así:

```
*p = 3.1415926;
```

el compilador dará un error diciendo que no puede asignarse un `void`. Hay que convertir `p` *temporalmente* en un puntero a `float`, así:

```
*(float *)p = 3.1415926;
```

La utilidad de esto está sobre todo en poder pasar a una función un puntero a un tipo que no queremos especificar en tiempo de compilación, porque la misma función podría admitir diferentes tipos (otro parámetro de la función podría especificar por ejemplo cómo usar el puntero). En realidad, no deja de ser un truco "sucio" para saltarse los tipos en casos en que no se puede hacer de otro modo.

Answer (score 1):

Estas en C++, y, en dicho lenguaje, el uso de `void` es para facilitar la *reutilización* de código C. Indicar que una función recibe `void`

```
int mifunct( void );
```

Es lo mismo que indicar que la función no recibe ningún argumento:

```
int mifunct( );
```

Esto te permite compilar código, original del lenguaje C, en un compilador C++ sin mayores problemas.

Si estás es C, la cosa cambia bastante: una función

```
int mifunct( void );
```

Es, al igual que en C++, una función que no recibe argumentos. Sin embargo, una función sin nada:

```
int mifunct( );
```

Indica una función **que puede recibir cualquier tipo/tipos de argumento**:

```
void myfunct( );

int main( void ) {
  myfunct( 10 );
  myfunct( "Hola mundo !\n" );

  return 0;
}

void myfunct( ) {

}
```

El código anterior compila sin errores.

Answer (score 0):

En realidad el uso de void en C es más que estético, conisdere el siguiente programa:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int incrementa();

int main()
{
    int y = incrementa();
    printf("Hello world! [%d]\n",y);
    return 0;
}

int incrementa(int n) {
    return n+1;
}
```

Si compila, notará que no marca errores en gcc, sin embargo hay un problema en la llamada a la función, requería un parámetro, pero el compilador no detecto, e incluso creo código ejecutable. Es es porque cuando no se colocan parámetros en el prototipo de una función el compilador asume que puede recibir cualquier numero de parámetros.

Si intenta compilar el mismo código pero colocando la palabra void en el prototipo encontrará que el compilador identifica correctamente el problema.

[1][Paso una cantidad de parámetros diferente a la definida, pero compila y funciona](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/471388/paso-una-cantidad-de-par%c3%a1metros-diferente-a-la-definida-pero-compila-y-funciona)