# Paso una cantidad de parámetros diferente a la definida, pero compila y funciona

Tags: c, abogado-del-lenguaje

En C, la **declaración** de una función con una lista de parámetros vacía le indica al compilador que los parámetros se **definirán** más tarde:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(); // DECLARAMOS una función con un número aún indeterminado de parámetros.

int main(void)
{
    f(1, 2, 3); // Llamamos a la función, aún sin definir, con tres parámetros.
    return 0;
}

void f(int x, int y, int z) // DEFINIMOS la función para recibir tres parámetros.
{
    printf("{%d, %d, %d}", x, y, z);
}
```

O eso es lo que yo creía, en realidad parece que el compilador no hace ninguna comprobación de los parámetros una vez declarada la función, ya que esto también funciona:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(); // DECLARAMOS una función con un número aún indeterminado de parámetros.

int main(void)
{
    f(1, 2, 3); // Llamamos a la función, aún sin definir, con tres parámetros.
    f(1, 2);    // Llamamos a la función, aún sin definir, con dos parámetros.
    f(1);       // Llamamos a la función, aún sin definir, con un parámetro.
    f();        // Llamamos a la función, aún sin definir, sin parámetros.
    f(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0); // Llamamos a la función con diez parámetros!!
    return 0;
}

void f(int x, int y, int z) // DEFINIMOS la función para recibir tres parámetros.
{
    printf("{%d, %d, %d}", x, y, z);
}
```

No sólo no da ningún error de compilación, si no que compila sin alarmas y [se ejecuta](https://tio.run/##RY1dCsIwEISf3VMMFSGFVeq/UvEukrQa0FRqK9qSs8fEFH1YZnb2Y0dOz1I6N9ZGXltV4PBolK5mlyPRs9IKpUhzIm0a3E7aiJCl1NOoFHPGgrH052EZXJR/7BnGirFmbBhbxo6xZ2SBqIumrQ2ynOyvL3S9GEHeUbpv4732vhRJP1GMODbhgHqs89@scx8) asignando valores indeterminados a las variables no facilitadas e ignorando las variables pasadas de más. ¿Qué es lo que está pasando? ¿No debería el compilador comparar la llamada a la función con la **definición** de la función y provocar error de compilación?

Comment: Por esas razones salió el C++ que tiene las verificaciones que indicas. El `C` te acepta todo.

Comment: ¿No dependerá del compilador que estés empleando? ¿Del sistema operativo? Yo siempre que he trabajado con C puro he tenido problemas de este tipo en los que no sólo me saltan Warning, sino que me reporta error de compilación por no tener la función declarada. Una vez que defino la función antes de emplearla desaparecen todos los errores/warnings y compila y se ejecuta con normalidad.

Comment: @Londo lo he probado con gcc 11.1, gcc 5.3, clang 11.0.1, clang 3.0.0, msvc 19.0 y msvc 19.14. Ha compilado en todos los casos.

Comment: En C, la lista vacía de argumentos indica **cualquier número de ellos y en cualquier posición**. Es una característica que lleva años *amenazada* de *deprecated* ... pero ahí sigue :-)

Comment: Puedes consultar la sección **`Notas`** de [aquí](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/variadic) y [aquí](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/function_declaration).

Comment: @Londo Asi es, al ser comportamiento indefinido va a depender completamente del compilador que se este utilizando.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TLDR:** Eso es comportamiento indefinido.

Puedes ir a [wg14.link](https://wg14.link/) y verificarlo con los otros
estándares, yo usare C99.

Primero que nada, definamos lo que es un prototipo de funcion:

> 6.2.1 al final del párrafo 2
>
> A function prototype is a declaration of a function that declares the types
> of its parameters.

Ahora vamos al Anexo J, y veamos lo que tiene que decir sobre lo que estas
haciendo:

> The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances:
>
> - [...]
> - For a call to a function without a function prototype in scope, the number
>   of arguments does not equal the number of parameters (6.5.2.2).

En este caso:

```c
void f();
```

No es un prototipo de función, ya que según el estándar:

> 6.7.5.3 al final del párrafo 14
>
> The empty list in a function declarator that is not part of a
> definition of that function specifies that no information about the number or
> types of the parameters is supplied.

No estas declarando los tipos de los parámetros (De hecho no das ninguna
información sobre ellos). Así que esto no cuenta como un prototipo de función.

Así que las siguientes llamadas:

```
    f(1, 2);    // Llamamos a la función, aún sin definir, con dos parámetros.
    f(1);       // Llamamos a la función, aún sin definir, con un parámetro.
    f();        // Llamamos a la función, aún sin definir, sin parámetros.
    f(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0); // Llamamos a la función con diez parámetros!!
```

Son comportamiento indefinido, ya que `f` no tiene un prototipo, y la cantidad
de argumentos con la que la llamas no coincide con la cantidad de parámetros
con la que la defines.

Recuerda que al caer en comportamiento indefinido todo vale, tu programa puede
funcionar y correr bien, tu programa puede fallar, puede funcionar aveces si y
otras no, puede no compilar, o cualquier otra cosa.

---

---

> ¿Qué es lo que está pasando? ¿No debería el compilador comparar la llamada
> a la función con la definición de la función y provocar error de compilación?

Al ser comportamiento indefinido, todo puede pasar. En este caso parece que los
compiladores prefieren darte algo que corra, en lugar de informarte de lo que
estas haciendo mal.

En este caso, para que el compilador te de un aviso de los errores que estas
cometiendo, puedes habilitar: `-Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes`.  Estos
no te explican que estas incurriendo en comportamiento indefinido, pero es lo
mas cercano que pude encontrar.

Y con respecto a esto:

> [...] No debería el compilador comparar la llamada
> a la función con la definición de la función [...]?

Parece ser que `clang` si lo hace. Se ves el assembler generado para la llamada
con parametros de mas:

```
; Elimina los parametros que no se usaran
mov     edi, 1
mov     esi, 2
mov     edx, 3
call    f
```

Comparado con `gcc`, que cuando tenias parámetros de mas lo lleno como si la
funcion los aceptara todos:

```c
mov     r9d, 6
mov     r8d, 5
mov     ecx, 4
mov     edx, 3
mov     esi, 2
mov     edi, 1
mov     eax, 0
call    f
```

[Link a godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Ksr9YPGPc).

Pero no te preocupes, ya que según el estándar:

> 6.11.6
>
> The use of function declarators with empty parentheses (not prototype-format
> parameter type declarators) is an obsolescent feature.

Ya que se esta volviendo obsoleta, supongo que en un futuro se removerá.