# Convertir de C a C++

Tags: c++, c

He hecho este programa en C y, como soy un iniciado en C++, no sé muy bien cómo hacer la conversión de un formato a otro.
Me estoy familiarizando con los conceptos (como #include  o cin >> _) pero precisaría de ayuda para todo esto, la cual agradecería enormemente.
Muchas gracias por su atención.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int i, j, T, N, C, ra, rn, ca, cn;
    scanf ("%d", &T);

    for (i = 0; i < T; i = i + 1)
    {
        scanf (" %d", &C);
        scanf (" %d", &N);
        for (j = 0; j < C; i = i + 1)
        {
            scanf (" %d %d %d %d", &ra, &ca, &rn, &cn);
            if ( (ra == rn) && (cn == ca)) printf ("0\n");
            else if ( (rn-ra == cn-ca) || (rn-ra == ca-cn)) printf ("1\n");
            else if ( (ra+ca) % 2 == (cn+ca) % 2 ) printf ("2\n");
            else printf ("no move\n");
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Prueba portarlo, compila tu código resultante y trae los errores que encuentras al hacerlo. La idea aquí no es que alguien _lo haga en tu lugar_

Comment: ¿Con portar te refieres a ejecutar? Es que no sé cómo portar...

Comment: Inténtalo. Busca cómo escribir estas instrucciones en C++. Compila tu código C++, mira qué falla y trae esos errores con ese código aquí. Todos aquí hemos aprendido de la misma forma y este foro no funciona "pidiendo cosas". Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 4):

En [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b):

- **Las cabeceras estándar carecen de extensión**: Por ninguna razón particular, pero es así.
- **No deben usarse cabeceras de [c](/questions/tagged/c)**: Existen versiones a C++ adaptadas de cabeceras de C, que tienen una `c` como prefijo y carecen de extensión, por ejemplo `<stdio.h>` ➜ `<cstdio>`. Deben usarse en caso de que la funcionalidad buscada sólo esté disponible en esa cabecera.
- **Las estructuras no requieren definición de tipo**: Para definir y usar un tipo estructura en C se necesita la palabra clave `struct`:

  ```
  // C
  struct S {}; // Definición
  struct S s;  // Instanciación
  ```

  En C++ las estructuras no requieren de la palabra clave `struct` para ser usadas:

  ```
  // C++
  struct S {}; // Definición
  S s;         // Instanciación
  ```
- **Las funciones que no reciben parámetros**: se declaran con lista de argumentos vacía, [lo cuál tiene una semántica diferente en C](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/471388/paso-una-cantidad-de-par%c3%a1metros-diferente-a-la-definida-pero-compila-y-funciona), que requiere que la lista de argumentos tenga un parámetro anónimo de tipo `void`:

  ```
  // C
  void funcion(void);

  // C++
  void funcion();
  ```
- **La memoria se reserva con `new` y se borra con `delete`**: No debe usarse `malloc` y `free`, que además de no ofrecer seguridad de tipos no tiene variante para formaciones, que en C++ es `new tipo[]` y `delete[] puntero`.
- **La comunicación con la consola**: se lee con `std::cin` (`c`onsole `in`put) y se escribe con `std::cout` (`c`onsole `out`put).
- **La palabra clave `auto`**: en C++ se usa para deducir el tipo de datos estáticamente, en C se usa para cualificar tipos; deberás cambiarla.
- **El cualificador `restrict`**: no existe en C++, tendrás que substituirlo por `const`.

Por lo demás, el código de C es compatible con código de C++, pero al revés no porque C:

- Carece de espacios de nombres.
- Carece de excepciones.
- No tiene plantillas.
- No tiene tipos referencia.
- No tiene sobrecarga de operadores.
- No tiene sobrecarga de funciones.
- No tiene lambdas.
- No tiene categorías de transformación (`static_cast`, `dynamic_cast`, `const_cast`, `reinterpret_cast`).
- <strike>No tiene tipo booleano nativo</strike>.
- No tiene literal de puntero nulo.
- No tiene `for` de rango.
- No tiene ligaduras estructuradas.
- No puedes devolver `void` en una función `void`.
- No es orientado a objetos.

  - No tiene clases (`class`).
  - Las estructuras no pueden tener funciones.
  - Las estructuras no se pueden auto-inicializar (carecen de constructor) ni lo contrario (carecen de destructor).

Comment: *"No puedes devolver void en una función void."* Como asi?

Comment: En C esto es ilegal: `void funcion(); void otra_funcion() { return funcion(); }`, pero en C++ es legal.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Hola. Una pregunta, quieres decir sin los parentesis? Porque estas llamando y no veo nada mal. Copile en los dos casos -con y sin parentesis-, y solo en el segundo caso da warning.

Comment: @JoseS.Daniel `funcion` tiene `void` como tipo de retorno y se usa como expresión de un `return` en otra función que tiene `void` como tipo de retorno; eso en C es ilegal mientras que en C++ no lo es.

Comment: *No tiene tipo booleano nativo...* A partir de C99, se añadió un tipo [boolean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type#C,_C++,_Objective-C,_AWK) nativo y es `_Bool`, usando la cabecera `stdbool.h`, se puede hacer uso de la macro `bool`.  *No puedes devolver void en una función void..* Esto me pareció interesante, en que parte del estándar lo especifica?

Comment: @MrDave1999 Si tienes que añadir una cabecera para usarlo, no es nativo. Por ejemplo ¿Qué cabecera tienes que incluir para usar `int`, `char`, `long`, `float` o `double`?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster En C++ el tipo `bool` es nativo. En C existe el tipo `_Bool`, es decir, para crear variables booleanas en C, deben ser declaradas con `_Bool`. La cabecera `stdbool.h` (que también fue agregado a partir de C99) ofrece una macro llamada `#define bool _Bool` para no tener que escribir `_Bool` de manera manual pero esto es opcional (o sea, puedes usar `_Bool` directamente en el código).

Comment: @MrDave1999 los identificadores que empiezan por un guión bajo (`_`) seguidos de una letra mayúscula están reservados para ser usados por el compilador y no deben ser usados en código. En C el booleano no es nativo, ningún tipo de dato nativo se comporta como describes.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster A partir de `C99` se agrego el tipo `_Bool` y sirve para declarar **variables booleanas de forma nativa**, lo puedes comprobar leyendo el [estándar](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) (**Pag 45 - 6.2.5 Types**). Al ser un tipo nativo, no es posible asignar el valor de una variable de tipo `int` a uno de tipo `_Bool` y es porque `_Bool` es un tipo nativo. Y con respecto a esto: *No puedes devolver void en una función void...* No encuentro nada en el estándar que confirme esa *afirmación*.

Comment: @MrDave1999 para usar `int` no hay que incluir `<stdint.h>` dando acceso al tipo `_Int` del que hay una macro para renombrarlo a `int`. Eso sucede porque es un tipo nativo y como tal, se puede usar sin incluir nada ni confiar en macro alguna. Respecto al tema `void`: *6.8.6.4 The return statement: A **return** statement with an expression shall not appear in a function whose return type is **void**.*

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster No lo digo yo, lo dice el mismo estándar: *6.2.5 An object declared as type **_Bool** is large enough to store the values 0 and 1*. Y lo vuelvo a repetir, no necesitas incluir ningún encabezado para usar el tipo `_Bool`. El tipo `_Bool` **es un tipo nativo de C** que sirve expresamente para declarar **variables booleanas**. [Aquí](https://www.onlinegdb.com/N7HpZv08k) tienes un ejemplo en vivo. Con respecto a lo otro, bueno, entonces una función `void` no puede devolver ninguna expresión, nada.

Comment: @MrDave1999 yo no estoy diciendo que el tipo no exista. Digo que no es nativo. El estándar también dice que los identificadores que empiezan por `_` y una letra mayúscula están reservados para cualquier uso. (estándar de C apartado *7.1.3 Reserved identifiers*) ¿Cómo un tipo nativo puede tener su uso reservado?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster *El estándar también dice que los identificadores que empiezan por _ y una letra mayúscula están reservados para cualquier uso..* Así es pero `_Bool` no actua como identificador, sino, como una palabra clave como `int`, `float`, etc. Para que un tipo sea un tipo nativo, debe ser propio del lenguaje y como dije anteriormente, puedes usar `_Bool` sin incluir `stdbool.h`. Así que `_Bool` es un tipo nativo y no lo digo yo, lo dice el mismo estándar.

Comment: Con respecto a esto: ¿Cómo un tipo nativo puede tener su uso reservado? `_Bool` no será usado como un identificador reservado por la implementación. Por ejemplo, no puede haber una variable llamada `_Bool` definida en la biblioteca estándar de C, porque `_Bool` es una palabra clave. **Conclusión:** Las palabras claves definidas en el estándar no pueden ser identificadores reservados.