# llamada incorrecta a una función pero aun así gcc genera el código ejecutable

Tags: c, gcc, compilador, prototipos

En el siguiente código, la llamada a la función incrementa() es incorrecta porque le falta un parámetro,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int incrementa(); /* el prototipo es incorrecto le falta un parámetro*/

int main()
{
    int y = incrementa(); /* error falta un parámetro*/
    printf("[%d]\n",y);
    return 0;
}

int incrementa(int n) {
    return n+1;
}
```

sin embargo aun asi se genera código sin generar ningún warning o error. Uso codeblocks para compilar y gcc (mingw), la linea de compilación que se emplea es:

```
gcc.exe -Wall -g  -c "main.c" -o obj\Debug\main.o
gcc.exe  -o borrame.exe main.o
```

esperaba que en la segunda linea se generará por lo menos un error de ligado. EL programa corre aunque el resultado es incorrecto (un número cualquiera)

¿alguna idea de por que si funciona? ¿cómo prevenir estos problemas?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Paso una cantidad de parámetros diferente a la definida, pero compila y funciona](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/471388/paso-una-cantidad-de-par%c3%a1metros-diferente-a-la-definida-pero-compila-y-funciona)

Comment: Si, muchas gracias. La solución es entonces usar void en aquellas funciones que no reciben parámetros. Asi si declaramos: ```int incementa(void)  ``` se genera un error: ```error: conflicting types for 'incrementa```